# SOLR: searching ngram field with whitespace not giving expected results

Tags: solr, lucene

I am having issues with getting the expected behavior from SOLR when performing a search on ngram fields. The query is as follows: *order:Test Order AND status:ACCEPTED* what I want the result to be is everything with the order "Test Order" and status ACCEPTED.

What I get is all kind of statuses instead. I am able to solve it by re-writing the questies to one of these two: *order:Test+Order AND status:ACCEPTED* or *order:Test AND order:Order AND status:ACCEPTED*

This query is performed from a Java backend based on user input. I could make something that replaces the whitespace with a + to fix the problem, but I am pretty new to SOLR and was hoping SOLR had a solution for this or I was using something wrong.

This leads me to believe that SOLR handles the whitespace as a new search, and since no field is specified it simply searches everything. I tried wrapping it with qotation marks, but the result is nothing, not sure why. The behaviour I want is for it to find every doc that has the word test or order in field order, and has the status ACCEPTED.

The fieldtype looks like this:

```
<fieldType name="text_general_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="40"/>

    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt"    ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Hoping someone can help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the phrase "Test Order" otherwise it's looking for "Order" in whatever your default field is and then "Test" in the order field so try:

order:(Test Order) AND status:ACCEPTED

Si